# Fadeout form on focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusout

How can I make a form fade out when focus is lost entirely? Or another way of putting it: How do I prevent the form from fading when the focus is just shifted from one input to another?

My failing approach is:

```
form.focusout(function(){
    form.fadeout();
});
```

I have tied to add an if statement counting the number of inputs with focus but to no benefit since the lostfocus fires before the new focus is set.

Comment: Why not use `mouseleave`-event ...?

Comment: Can include `html` ?

Comment: Im working in a django project where the relevant html and javascript is scattered over a complex form :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting a timeout, and then if another input has focus, clear the time out to avoid the fadeout:

```
var timeout;
form.find('input').on('focusout', function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {form.fadeout();}, 2000);
});

form.find('input').on('focusin', function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

Comment: If this works, will it do nicely. Probably give a better UX feel then what I tried to do to... I'll try it out thank you!